# Howland source, MAX current output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source

How would one determine the maximum current output you could achieve from an improved Howland source given a specific op amp? In other words, what do I need to look at in the op amp's datasheet? (I am using a TL074)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The op-amp has to supply all the output current plus a bit for the feedback. So you want to look at the current that the op-amp can supply. In the case of the TL074 it can supply 10V into 2K with a +/-15V supply, so that's 5mA, guaranteed.

It can probably supply quite a bit more current but there is nothing guaranteed, not even a typical number.

If you need high output current, you should probably pick a different op-amp with guaranteed specifications in that department. Op-amps such as the LT1014 are often specified with 600 ohm loads, so more like 15mA. There are also power op-amps that can handle amperes on the output stage. Or high voltage.

Comment: Would you need to use a push-pull on the Howland source if you wanted to add output transistors for increased drive?

Comment: @DKNguyen The nice thing about Howland is that you can make a bipolar or even AC current source. If you want a low-distortion AC current source you're going to need to make an output stage that looks like an audio amplifier output stage with enough bias so that there's minimal crossover distortion. If it's unipolar or only does one polarity or the other at a  time, you could get away with a couple emitter followers, very simple.

Comment: Would the "Short-circuit current" in the datasheet of an Op-Amp like the TLV4172 be a good indicator of the upper limit of output? 

I noticed that the TL074 doesn't have this value but other more expensive opamps do have this value.

Comment: Most op-amps limit current into a short circuit, so that's a probable 'typical' maximum possible current (so it provides a bit of information), but it's not a very good number to use, nor does it even offer much guidance, for normal operation into a given load.

Comment: I see. I noticed that the TL074 has a graph of "Max output voltage vs Load resistance" And one can see that you can get higher current outputs at lower voltages (Eg. 10v into 600 Ohm for TL074). Is the reason you wouldn't use that graph because it's only valid for 25°C, whereas 10v into 2K is valid for all temps? Or have I misunderstood that graph and it's not even relevant here? Thanks!

Comment: It's relevant, and you can use that to get some kind of idea of where the typical limits are and compare that with the guaranteed swing (which will be less than the typical) and maybe scale it or get an idea of how much safety margin you think you need, but without knowledge of the causes of the behavior and reasons for the variations there is some risk involved.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "paper" design, you should definitely breadboard it and do measurement in your desired application. The output current capacity will depend somewhat on the voltage drop in the driver stage. You must also take into account thermal limits: if the output stage will dissipate too much, the op-amp may shut down. If the current range needed is small, you can perhaps help the op-amp by providing some of the current with a resistive source or sink. One approach is to make the op-amp's output current zero when the current is on-target, assuming that the compliance range of the load is small, or if the load is outright resistive.